# Ruby on Rails validate for multiple choice test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

What is the best way to validate a answer input by a user, validation rules below:

```
Examples of formats allowed 1, 2, 3, 4...to 12 

The value is 2 answers for 12 choices
```

model:

```
class Questions < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :answers, presence: true
end
```

Html:

```
<h3>question</h3>
<% (1..12).each do |x| %>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-danger btn-circle">
    <input type="checkbox" name="question[answer][]" id="optionsCheckbox<%= x %>" value="<%= x %>" />
    <%= x %>
  </label>
</div>
<% end %>
</ul>
<%= f.button :submit, "submit", class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

in controller:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [ :new ]
before_action :find_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def create
    @question = Question.new(ticket_params)
    @question.user = current_user
    if @question.save
        redirect_to new_charge_path
    else
        render :new, alert: "Oops, something went wrong..."
    end
  end

    def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(answer: [])
  end

  def find_question
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

answer is a string in questions table

It is an array, he have 12 choices and 2 possible responses. Like a multiple choice quiz.. I would just define the possible number of choice (2 choices)

That is my submit response in console:

```
Started POST "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-24 18:26:08 +0200
 Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mAoBIf9jqDoungeeFKe6KitIf0ahAxhi6rVODmz6v1xGExYeVAVL8qXBfJj37KTpIkBBZJV2F1MRuBJKA==", "question"=>{"answer"=>["2", "8"], "commit"=>"Submit"}
 User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" =  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 2  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (27.0ms)  INSERT INTO "questions" ("answer", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (1, 2 ) RETURNING "id"  [["answer", "[\"2\", \"8\"]"], ["created_at", 2016-05-24 16:26:08 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-05-24 16:26:08 UTC], ["user_id", 6]]
 (23.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/charge/new
Completed 302 Found in 112ms (ActiveRecord: 51.3ms)
```

Comment: do you want to check if the question is answered right or wrong. OR your requirement is something else

Comment: no, just validate that there are two choices Selected

Comment: Do you want to send that after submit  button? OR you want to show it like a flash message? Its not clear by your above code. please elaborate more.

Comment: It is an array with 12 responses possible, user select 2 responses and submit. After the submit all is good.. But for validate the submit I need a validation on the number of select answers

Comment: So you want to send the `id` or `parameters` of `selected answers` to the controller?

Comment: ok, Now i got it, what you want. Can you tell me what are your parameters when you submit your form.

Comment: You need the controller?

Comment: No, i need the `params` in console, when you click on submit button.

Comment: I post the console response and i past the controller above

Comment: use `params([:question][:answer])`, It will make array available to you in controller

Comment: No, my controller work find

Comment: If I change that the controller not work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the requirement, but seems like something like this:

```
class Question...
  validate :validate_answers

  def validate_answers
    unless answers.length == 2
      errors.add(:answers, 'must have 2 selected')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, your checkbox name needs to match the model attribute.  `<input type="checkbox" name="questions[answer][]` should be `name="questions[answers][]`

Comment: Sorry I have an error in the code, it's  '<input type="checkbox" name="question  [answer ] [ ]' . Thanks for your help but your solution not work for me, I have test with .length and .count ....

Comment: what is the value of question.answers.inspect in the controller?